# Windows Azure table storage or SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have an application that looks up data for a page. The data is looked up by primary key and row key in table storage.

I am considering SQL Azure storage. Is there some advantage in my going to this kind of storage being that the look up will always be very direct. Note that I do NOT need any reporting. ALL I want is single row look up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use Sql Azure and when should I use table Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930368/when-should-i-use-sql-azure-and-when-should-i-use-table-storage)

Answer (score 2):

> I am considering SQL Azure storage. Is there some advantage in my going to this kind of storage being that the look up will always be very direct. Note that I do NOT need any reporting. ALL I want is single row look up

Assuming that your requirements are fully stated as will only ever need single row access, and assuming that you only want to know about advantages and not disadvantages, then the only advantages I can think of are that SQL azure offers:

- time-based subscription pricing instead of pricing per transaction
- options for backup (in CTP)
- options for replication/synchronisation
- more client library options (e.g. Entity Framework, Linq2SQL, etc)
- more data types supported
- more options for moving your app outside of Azure if you ever want to

Answer (score 0):

Use Table Storage if you don't need relational database functionality.

Comment: Yeah but what is the reason why I should use Table Storage?

Comment: You only need to use SQL Azure when you need a 'proper' database.  Table storage is for the most part a much cheaper option when it has all the functionality you need.